# How to separate journeys from GPS traces using ArcGIS/ QGIS?

Tags: gps

I am facing a GPS Data Preprocessing problem. I have GPS traces of buses which traveled from one place (bus station) to another. This file contains relevant (eg:- Data recorded between the starting bus station and ends with the destination stop) and irrelevant GPS traces (eg- traces recorded from bus station to the home of the bus driver). All the data of the month is in the same file. Looking for a efficient preprocessing technique **to separate journeys from the file**. The data fields in the files are **"timestamp", "lat","lon"**. Can somebody suggest any techniques for this preprocessing step?

Comment: You need to know the starting and end time of the journeys and do selections on the field **timestamp** but surely they don't start and finish at the exact same time each day so if you have a monthly file it might be difficult to automatically process it ...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer system operates.

Comment: An initial idea could be to draw a polygon that contains the work route and then only keep the data wich is spatially within that polygon. If you would like, try it and accommodate your question to a specific problem that arises when doing so.